Passing a parameter when dynamically adding buttons in Summernote
I am creating dynamical custom buttons for my summernote wysiwygs, but i'm running into a problem. I want to pass the data I'm iterating through to the button's render function, but since it is already being passed the context as a parameter, I'm a bit clueless here.
Here's the relevant code:
var formButtons = {};
var formButtonIds = [];
if(FormsModule.currentForm) {
    for(var i=0; i<FormsModule.currentForm.fields.length; i++) {
        var field = FormsModule.currentForm.fields[i];
        var fieldId = 'button_' + i;
        formButtons[fieldId] = (function (context) {
            console.log(context);
            console.log(field);
            var ui = $.summernote.ui;
            var tooltip = 'Insert ' + field.title;
            // create button
            var button = ui.button({
                contents: HelperModule.getTitle(field.title),
                tooltip: tooltip,
                click: function () {
                    context.invoke("editor.insertText", '<span clas="field-input-button">#' + field.title + '#</span>');
                },
            });

            return button.render();
        });
        formButtonIds.push(fieldId);
    }
} 
$("#form-modal #form-form .wysiwyg").each(function(index, wysiwyg) {
    var content = $(wysiwyg).summernote('code');
    $(wysiwyg).summernote('destroy');
    $(wysiwyg).summernote({
        buttons: formButtons,
        toolbar: [
            ["style", ["style"]],
            ['font', ['bold', 'underline', 'clear']],
            //['fontname', ['fontname']],
            ["color", ["color"]],
            ["para", ["ul", "ol", "paragraph"]],
            ["mybutton", formButtonIds],
            ["table", ["table"]],
            ["insert", ["link"]],
            ["view", ["codeview"]],
        ],
    });
    $(wysiwyg).summernote('code', content);
})

If I try and pass the field to the formButtons[x] function, it (replaces the context's value):
    formButtons[fieldId] = (function (context) {
        console.log(context);
        console.log(field);
        var ui = $.summernote.ui;
        var tooltip = 'Insert ' + field.title;
        // create button
        var button = ui.button({
            contents: HelperModule.getTitle(field.title),
            tooltip: tooltip,
            click: function () {
                context.invoke("editor.insertText", '<span clas="field-input-button">#' + field.title + '#</span>');
            },
        });

        return button.render();
    })(field); 

The console.log of both field and context are the field value

Please don't tag your titles. See [ask]. Also, this question doesn't seem related to Bootstrap.

Looks to me as if you have the field.title rendered at click time, when it is out of scope.
Try this:
formButtons[fieldId] = (function(context) {
  console.log(context);
  console.log(field);
  var ui = $.summernote.ui;
  var tooltip = 'Insert ' + field.title;
  // create button
  var button = ui.button({
    contents: HelperModule.getTitle(field.title),
    tooltip: tooltip,
    data: { fieldtitle: field.title },
    click: function() {
      context.invoke("editor.insertText", `<span clas="field-input-button">#${this.dataset.fieldtitle}#</span>`);
    },
  });

  return button.render();
})(field);


if I pass the field parameter like that, the context parameter is replaced by the field parameter thus I lose the context

And what does that mean? What is the expected result and the actual result. Can you show using a picture or something?
